# How to get ∴ on a keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard

How do I type ∴ on a keyboard in Windows 7? That is, which Alt-combination is it?
I don't want to have to search, copy and paste every time I want to write 'therefore'.

Comment: Ddi you try? ALT-8756 (num pad)

Comment: Which Windows? Which application?

Comment: @Ofiris that returns '4'.

Comment: @terdon Windows 7. Sorry, didn't think of it being different for each OS. And it's in Opera, my browser, but the num symbols usually work the same everywhere.

Comment: @keirbtre no worries, you may be right and it is irrelevant but you (or, at least, I) never know...

Comment: This symbol is Unicode +2234, but not all programs accept Unicode input by default. It also gets more complicated because the symbol is not in all fonts. If you check out the Character Map (Start->All Programs->Accessories->System Tools->Character Map) you can see that Arial does not contain U+2234 (symbols are sorted by unicode number) but Cambria Math does have it.

Answer (score 5):

In some Microsoft applications such as Word, typing `2234` followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> will convert it to ∴

Alternatively, you can enable hexadecimal input via the number pad across Windows by setting the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method\EnableHexNumpad` to have a string value of `1`. After a reboot, holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while typing <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> all on the number pad should work.